# Generating an evenly sampled array from unevenly sampled data in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sample

The problem is that I want to reduce the amount of data for plots and analysis. I'm using Python and Numpy. The data is unevenly sampled, so there is an array of timestamps and an array of corresponding values. I want it to be at least a certain amount of time between the datapoints. I have a simple solution here written in Python, where the indicies are found where there is at least one second between the samples:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.array([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.3, 5.0 ]) # seconds
v = np.array([0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 ])

idx = [0]
last_t = t[0]
min_dif = 1.0 # Minimum distance between samples in time
for i in range(1, len(t)):
    if last_t + min_dif <= t[i]:
        last_t = t[i]
        idx.append(i)
```

If we look at the result:

```
--> print idx
[0, 4, 5, 6, 9]

--> print t[idx]
[ 0.  1.  2.  4.  5.]
```

The question is how can this be done more effectively, especially if the arrays are really long? Are there some built in NumPy or SciPy methods that do something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While, like @1443118, I'd suggest to use `pandas`, you may want to try something with `np.histogram`.

First, get an idea of the number of bins (intervals of `min_dif` s) you would need:

```
>>> bins = np.arange(t[0], t[-1]+min_dif, min_dif) - 1e-12
```

The `t[-1]+min_dif` is to ensure we take the last point, the `-1e-12` a hack to avoid having the `4.0` of your example counted in the last bin: it's just an offset to make sure we close the intervals on the right.

```
>>> (counts, _) = np.histogram(t, bins)
>>> counts
array([4, 1, 1, 0, 3])
>>> counts.cumsum()
array([4, 5, 6, 6, 9])
```

So, `v[0:4]` is your first sample, `v[4:5]` your second... you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of using histogram for this. So to get the same indecies as in my original example one would just have to use `np.unique` function and a `[0]` to the start.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be by interpolation, using e.g. `numpy.interp`:

```
vsampled = numpy.interp(numpy.arange(t[0], t[-1]), t, v)
```

This will not give you the indices of the values though. However, it will generate values by interpolation even for points in t where no data in the input arrays is available.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it wasn't exactly interpolation I was looking for. Lets say I have 100.000 datapoints that I want to plot, but I know that the screen only shows 1000 points across. Then there would be a lot of redundant data. To be clearer, I want to send the data over the net, and then plot it using javascript on the client side. The bandwidth is therefore important; so is the processing time, as the response has to be sent of quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a solution doing *exactly* what you want, but while it does not seem too elegent to me, this should do *approximately* what you want without doing interpolation. It will give at most one value (the leftmost) for every second:

```
# Assuming that t is sorted...
# Create all full seconds.
seconds = np.arange(int(t[0]), int(t[-1]) + 1)

# find the indexes for all
idx = np.searchsorted(t, seconds)
idx = np.unique(idx) # there might be duplicates if a second has no data in it.
```

For your example it gives the same result, but it will usually allow smaller or larger differences of course (anything between 0 and 2 seconds)...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this. It is pretty straightforward to generate regularly spaced time series and then resample data to some specific frequency. See [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)
and look at subsection on resampling about half way down the page.